# RuntimeError: To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU"

Tags: python, theano

I have installed theano with

```
conda install theano
```

on Ubuntu 16.04.
Now I have import problems

```
import theano
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values
    sectiondict = self._sections[section]
KeyError: 'blas'
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1252, in check_mkl_openmp
    raise RuntimeError('To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU" in your environement.')
RuntimeError: To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU" in your environement.
```

What does this mean?How to check if everything if BLAS is properly installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved this,it seems that MKL 2018 has some serious problems

```
conda uninstall mkl=2018
conda install mkl=2017
```

Comment: Other answers around did not work but this one did. Thanks!

Comment: I tried that, and ended up without some packages (numpy, pandas...)

Comment: On windows, I needed to reinstall theano: C:\>conda install theano

Comment: When uninstalling mkl=2018, on my Win10, together pymc, seaborn and theano would be removed too. @Alema-Z you could just reinstall them back, for instance, `conda install mkl=2017 pymc seaborn theano`

Comment: Thank you Richard for your post. Killed over 30 minutes till found this port, the conda install mkl=2017 informed me that some of the installed packages would be downgraded -> selected "y" -> now no more errors after selecting import theano. Yes!!

Comment: This answer is so dated it really should be augmented with the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just add below line to ~/.bashrc

```
export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
```

I had the same problem and this fixed the issue for me.

Ubuntu - 16.04
Python - 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

I faced same error on Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04. To solve this, I added an `export` statement to my *`.zshrc`* as:

```
export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
```

And ran the following for compiling the configuration file

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Following this, I was able to `import theano` without any errors.